# Right-discrete index set

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

I have encountered the concept "right-discrete" index set, which I have never heard of in a textbook (Klenke, Probability Theory). In particular, say that $I\subset [0, \infty)$ is right-discrete if $t < \inf(I \cap (t,\infty))$ for all $t\ge 0$.

I have two questions related to this definition.

(1) The textbook claims that $I$ is countable, but how can I show this? I can see that if $I$ contains a nondegenerate interval $I_0$, then a point $t \in \mathrm{Int}(I_0)$ violates the condition, but is this enough to claim that $I$ is countable?

(2) Is there a definition for "left-discrete"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-discreteness just says that for every $t \ge 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $(t, t + \delta)$ is disjoint from $I$. In particular this means that you can associate a set of disjoint intervals to $I$ by picking such a $\delta$ for every $t \in I$, and such a set must be countable. The standard way to prove that is by picking a rational number in each of the intervals.

The definition makes sense for any subset of $\Bbb R$, and "left-discrete" would simply mean that $-I$ is right-discrete, or equivalently, for every $t$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $(t - \delta, t)$ is disjoint from $I$, or equivalently, that for every $t$, we have $t > \sup I \cap (-\infty, t)$.

Note that with this definition, not every discrete set is right-discrete - for instance, consider $\{1 + \tfrac 1n \mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{1 -\tfrac 1n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. But nor is every right-discrete set discrete - for example, consider $\{1\} \cup \{1 -\tfrac 1n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$.

Edit: In fact, I have just noticed that a subset $I$ of $\Bbb [0, \infty)$ is right-discrete if and only if it is [well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), meaning that each of its non-empty subsets has a least element.

Indeed, let such an $I$ be right-discrete. Let $I' \subseteq I$ be a non-empty subset. Let $x = \inf I'$ (note that $x \ge 0$, and in particular $x > -\infty$, because $I \subseteq [0, \infty)$. This assumption was critical! EG $\Bbb Z$ is also right-discrete but not well-ordered). We will show that $x \in I'$ (then clearly $x$ is the least element of $I'$). So suppose not - then there is a $\delta$ with $[x, x + \delta)$ disjoint from $I$. This is absurd as this would imply that $\inf I' \ge x + \delta$. So $I'$ has a least element, so $I$ is well-ordered.

Conversely, suppose $I$ is well-ordered. Let $t \ge 0$. Consider $I' = \{x \in I \mid x > t\} = I \cap (t, \infty)$. If this is empty there's nothing to show. But if it's non-empty, then it has a least element, and hence its infimum is that least element, which is strictly greater than $t$. So $I$ is right-discrete. This concludes the proof.

This may provide you with some more intuition/some more keywords to look up to gather some intuition. Well-ordered sets are heavily studied in set theory and order theory. They are closely related to "ordinals". In some sense, they model "index sets for transfinite processes", which is perhaps sort of what this book is using them for. More formally, well-ordered sets are exactly the totally ordered sets for which you can use the principles of strong induction and strong recursion.

Really you should consider this point to be the end of my answer. But I've written some more waffle about well-ordered sets and what they can look like, if that interests you.

My favourite silly example of a "real-life" transfinite process is [this train in Q13](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/II/Logic/2021-2022/logic20222.pdf), which stops at uncountably many stations. Most other examples of transfinite processes I know come from set theory. It may help to look at some examples of well-ordered sets. One is $\{1 - \tfrac 1n \mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{2 - \tfrac 1n \mid n \in \Bbb N\} = \{0, \tfrac 12, \tfrac 23, \tfrac 34, \dotsc, 1, \tfrac 32, \tfrac 53, \tfrac 74, \dotsc\}$. You might imagine what happens if you try to "step through" this set starting from the left. At time $0$, you are at $0$. At time $1$, you are at $\tfrac 12$, and so on. You will never reach $1$ in finite time, but you can reach $1$ at "the first infinite time after all the finite times". This is the ordinal $\omega$. Then at time $\omega + 1$, you are at $\tfrac 32$, and so on. We would say that this set has "order-type" $\omega + \omega = \omega \cdot 2$. So you could use this set to index a process which had infinitely many successive steps, followed by another sequence of infinitely many successive steps. If this set went on in this way for each integer, it would have order-type $\omega \cdot \omega$.

It's well-known that if you take any well-ordered set (not necessarily as a subset of $\Bbb R$), then it embeds into $[0, \infty)$ if and only if it is countable. The necessity of countability is exactly what my first paragraph was about.

Hence if you understand the "countable ordinals", then you understand the possible "order-types" of right-discrete sets in $[0, \infty)$. In some ways there is a lot of intuition you can have about countable ordinals, but also they can be really weird and exotic. There's a whole [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal) about these ordinals and how strange they can get - you quickly get into logic-related issues about provability and computability and so on.

I'll give a short construction to show some of the ways you can make medium-sized (note that this sense of "size" has nothing to do with cardinality) well-ordered sets. If $I_0, I_1, I_2, \dotsc$ is a sequence of well-ordered subsets of $[0, \infty)$, then define a new well-ordered subset $\sum_n I_n$ as follows:
Firstly, note that the image of each $I_n$ under $\tanh$ is still a well-ordered set, with the same order type as $I_n$, but it's a subset of $[0, 1)$. So we can jam $I_n$ into a set $I_n' \subseteq [n, n + 1)$ by then also translating it. Then let $\sum_n I_n = I_0' \cup I_1' \cup I_2' \cup \dotsb$. This construction lets us "glue together" a sequence of well-ordered sets, in order.

Now start with $I_0 = \{0\}$.
Inductively, define $I_{n + 1} = \sum_m I_n$ to be a sum of infinitely many identical copies of $I_n$. (We would say $I_n$ has the order-type $\omega^n$).

Now let $J_0 = \sum_n I_n$ be the sum of all $I_n$. (We would say $J_0$ has order-type $\omega^\omega$). This is already a pretty weirdly big well-ordered set, but they get waaaay bigger. For instance, you can get up to sets of order-type $\omega + \omega^\omega + \dotsb = \omega^{\omega^{\omega^{⋰}}}$, and much bigger than that. To start getting to that sort of size, it's helpful to define not just sums but also products of these sets. But I think I'll stop here!